# Moving Emails within Public Folders without copying

Tags: exchange, outlook-2003, public-folders

To save time, our users would like to drag emails from one public folder to a subfolder (IE - the folder is named "New" and the subfolder of it is "Reviewed") - however, when they do this it copies the file instead of moving it.  Is there anywhere to set up exchange server to treat drag & drop as a move instead of copy?

I'm not super familiar with Exchange Server, so please bear with me if my question makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd553036.aspx) should help you out.

> Move Public Folders  To move a public
>   folder to a new location in the same
>   tree, follow these steps:
>   1. In Outlook, right-click the public folder with which you want to work,
>   and then select Cut.
>   2. Right-click the folder into which you want to move the folder, and then
>   select Paste.

If it doesn't work initially, you'll need to check the permissions for that user on the folder/items.

Edit:  For items, it looks like [this](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Public-Folder-Basics-Part2.html) might have the answer for you (under the section Folder Administration).  If you go to the properties of the folder, you can set the drag/drop actions.  Unfortunately, I don't have a mail enabled folder to test with, so this is the best I have right now.

Comment: That works for folders, but not for individual emails within folders.  All users seem to have the same issue.  We've checked user settings and there doesn't seem to be anything that would prevent moving instead of copying.  Thank you for the suggestion though. :)

Comment: @Jessie, I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: We looked into this and the only options were "Move/Copy" or "Forward".  Oh well.  It looks like the easiest way to move instead of copy is to press shift while you drag and drop.  
Thanks for your help, Holo.

Answer (score 0):

Most people drag and drop using the left mouse button. In Outlook (or Windows File Explorer), the left drop does a default action depending on the source and destination. For public folders, the default action is copy. You can use keyboard modifiers to change the action performed, and you noticed that shift will do a Move. You can also use the mouse's right button for the drag drop operation and you will be presented with a context menu asking which operation you wish to perform. (Move, Copy or Cancel)

Answer (score 0):

To move messages between public folders, hold the Shift key down and drag the message.  I know this is annoying behavior that MS has not chosen to change in the dozen plus years I have been using public folders.